# Wrong 2nd argument type with fragment

Tags: java, android

Reading "Head First Android Programming", it's kinda outdated, so code which is shown in this book is also outdated.
[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2csxp.png)

Android Studio says: Wrong 2nd argument type.
Found: com.xfunny.workout.WorkoutDetailFragment', required: android.app.Fragment'

```
public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private long workoutId;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    View view = getView();
    if(view != null){
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        Workout workout = Workout.workouts[(int)workoutId];
        title.setText(workout.getName());
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDescription);
        description.setText(workout.getDescription());
    }
}

public void setWorkout(long id){
    this.workoutId = id;
}
```

}

Comment: please post code (not as a picture) of `WorkoutDetailFragment`

Comment: Does `WorkoutDetailFragment` extend `Fragment` ?

Comment: Yes, it extends Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Do somthing like this

```
android.app.Fragment details = new WorkoutDetailFragment();
```

instead of

```
WorkoutDetailFragment details = new WorkoutDetailFragment();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. It says "Incompatible types" when I use `android.app.Fragment` instead of 'WorkoutDetailFragment'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `AppCompatActivity` you need to use the `Fragment` from the support library, ie `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

And of course if you switch to the support Fragment, you will need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. It says "Incompatible types" when I use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: You have to change the import statement for the Fragment in WorkoutDetailFragment class

Comment: And please change the Import statement for the FragmentManager as well

Comment: Okay, in this case this method can't resolve my method `setWorkout(long)`.

Comment: cast the fragment object to WorkoutDetailFragment